# Converting .Rd file to plain text

Tags: r, plaintext, rd

I'm trying to convert R documentation files (extension .Rd) into plain text. I am aware that RdUtils contains a tool called [Rdconv](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/r-project/arch/i386_rhel3/lib/R/library/base/html/RdUtils.html), but as far as I know it can only be used from the command line. Is there a way to access Rdconv (or a similar conversion tool) from within an R session?

Comment: Make a call to `system`?

Answer (score 7):

Try

```
tools::Rd2txt("path/to/file.Rd")
```

Comment: See other export options on the `?tools::Rd2txt` help page

Answer (score 2):

You may always invoke a system command e.g. with the `system2` function:

```
input <- '~/Projekty/stringi/man/stri_length.Rd'
output <- '/tmp/out.txt'
system2('R', paste('CMD Rdconv -t txt', filename, '-o', output))
readLines(output)
## [1] "Count the Number of Characters"
## ...
```

Make sure that R is in your system's search path. If not, replace the first argument of `system2()` above with full path, e.g. `C:\Program Files\R\3.1\bin\R.exe`.